# In Apache Spark, why setting "spark.task.cpus" is useless?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/configuration.html

The option should theoretically allow each task to occupy 2 cores. Now if I have a machine with 16 cores and run the following program:

```
      TestSC = <... initialising spark context here>

      TestSC.setLocalProperty("spark.task.cpus", "2")

      val rdd = TestSC.parallelize(1 to 100, 100).map { i =>
        Thread.sleep(99999999)
        i
      }

      rdd.collect()
```

It should allow 8 tasks to be executed concurrently. But when I go to Spark UI it still shows 16 tasks being executed at the same time. What is going on here? Was this option disabled somehow?

Comment: can you try setting like this - `val conf = new SparkConf(false)
      .set("spark.executor.cores", "1")
      .set("spark.task.cpus", "2")     
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)`

Comment: Would you please give the exact reference or clarify why "the option should theoretically allow each task to occupy 2 cores"?

Answer (score 0):

Set the property before creating spark context, like this:

```
val config = new SparkConf().set("spark.tasks.cpus","2").setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(config)
```

The setting should take effect when spark context is created like this.